# Handle deep linking in cordova app built on meteorjs (myapp://)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, meteor, url-scheme

I'm building a meteorjs app and deploying it as a native (cordova) app for Android and iOS.

I need to deep link to my app, so I can launch it by following a link on a website.

I've implemented URL Scheme using the cordova plugin by Eddy Verbruggen (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme) and I managed to get my app launched by following a link of the "myapp://" format.

The problem is that, even though the app is getting successfully launched, the handleOpenUrl hook is not getting triggered.

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    handleOpenURL = function handleOpenURL(url) {
        console.log("received url: " + url);
        // parse url and proceed accordingly
    }
});
```

Nothing gets logged. So I have no way of passing any parameters to my app, or even detect that the app was launched via a link that follows the 'myapp://' URL scheme.

Also, I noticed that even though my app is already open, if I switch to the browser and click on a special "myapp://" link, instead of switching to my (already open) app, a new instance of the app is getting launched.

*[edit] Turned out the two problems were related. Once I prevented a new instance of the app from being initialized, the handleOpenUrl function was triggered successfully.*

I'm using the Android emulator for all my tests. I haven't had the chance to test on iOS yet.

*[edit] iOS didn't give this problem at all. It was only an Android problem.*

If anyone out there has any experience on implementing custom URL scheme in meteorjs, your feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: How were you able to get your custom url to work in android on the emulator? I'm having trouble getting the emulator to register it but it works great in ios

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue I was facing. Here is the solution, for anybody else who is facing similar problems.

First of all, it was only occurring on Android. iOS had no problem whatsoever to launch the app and trigger the handleOpenUrl function.

The two issues that I was facing on Android turned out that there were related to each other. The fact that a new instance of the app was triggered every time, prevented the handleOpenUrl function from being triggered.

Both problems were fixed by adding a single line of code on the mobile-config.js file:

```
App.setPreference("AndroidLaunchMode", "singleTask");
```